# Reuse views from other IIS Application in the same site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I've got the following scenario.

I'v created an application in the past that is hosted on IIS. That solution is created in ASP.NET MVC (5).

Now I have to develop an new application but I want to embed the new features in the same site but using a complete new visual studio solution. This because the application functionality has no relation with the existing part. But the previous site could be used as a business dashboard.

Is it possible to reuse the existing layout hosting the new application as an IIS application in the same site without duplicating the existing layout-code (which references controllers in the existing application).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution will be to: [Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a seperate DLL](http://dllhttp://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)

Another solution can be a pre build event that knows where to take these files from and joing them to the project, it is complicated to do so and probably not bullet proof...